# Change div color with condition on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need help, i have `div` like this

```
<div id="namacoc" tabindex="1" class="filled-text" placeholder="Input your name" contenteditable ></div>
<div id="position" tabindex="1" class="filled-text" placeholder="Input your position" contenteditable></div>    
<button type="button" id="btncontinue" class="btn btn-wide btn-blue">Continue</button>
```

my porblem is, i wanna check that `div` like validation. 
**Example :**  If `namecoc` doesn't have `value`. `div namecoc` will instead change color to `red`, when namecoc have value that will be change `normal color (black)`, while i selected to another div or press button.

**NOTE :** I'm using div, not input form, cause the bootstrap wont change my  text background color on active. So i'm using `div`. 
Sorry my English so bad.

Comment: @PankajParkar : u seem note read my NOTE, i cant used input cause bootstrap doesnt allow me too create new style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest you to use `input` only, content editable do have its issues with different browsers.

**Try like this.**

```js
$("#btncontinue").click(function() {
  $("input").each(function() {
    $.trim($(this).val()) == "" ?
      $(this).addClass("invalid") : $(this).removeClass("invalid");
  });
});

$("input").on("blur", function() {
  $.trim($(this).val()) == "" ?
    $(this).addClass("invalid") : $(this).removeClass("invalid");
});
```

```css
.invalid {
  border: red 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="namacoc" tabindex="1" class="filled-text" placeholder="Input your name" contenteditable></input>
<input id="position" tabindex="1" class="filled-text" placeholder="Input your position" contenteditable></input>
<button type="button" id="btncontinue" class="btn btn-wide btn-blue">Continue</button>
```

Comment: but is still red when i filled div and selected another div :(

Comment: @Wolfzmus are you trying to use the above logic with divs ?? i you want the validation to happen on blur then we can modify the above code.

Comment: @Wolfzmus :)  Glad to Help

Answer (score 0):

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(".filled-text"), function (node) {
  node.onfocus = function () {
    this.className += " active";

    var text = this.innerHTML;

    if ((this.id === "namacoc"  && text === "Input your name") ||
        (this.id === "position" && text === "Input your position")) {

      this.innerHTML = "";
    }
  };

  node.onblur = function () {
    this.className = this.className.replace(" active", "");

    if (this.innerHTML === "") {
      if (this.id === "namacoc") {
        this.innerHTML = "Input your name";
      } else {
        this.innerHTML = "Input your position";
      }

      this.className = this.className.replace(" normal", "") + " empty";
    } else {
      this.className = this.className.replace(" empty", "") + " normal";
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.filled-text {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 24px 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.filled-text.placeholder {
  color: #d0d0d0;
}

.filled-text.empty {
  color: red;
}

.filled-text.active,
.filled-text.normal {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div id="namacoc"  class="filled-text placeholder" contenteditable>Input your name</div>
<div id="position" class="filled-text placeholder" contenteditable>Input your position</div>
```